Cyclone DDS Message traffic bandwidth depends on interfaces even when using ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1
When setting up a robot, I found ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 to be useful in enuring consistent message traffic frequency and speed within a number of nodes running in a docker container.
I had a eth interface, wifi interface and a loopback interface. The eth interface isn't usually connected during operation.
However I've recently modified my interfaces, removing the wifi harware and adding a slow PPPD interface over serial, that is there to share information between hosts via a non-ros2 communication.
what I've noticed is that the normal generation of messages slows down and effectively stops after a short while... as indicated by the information comming out of the PPPD interface. When I connect a cable to the eth port, then the information increases to the rate I expect, including information that should have been generated and probably sitting in a buffer. It appears that the ros2 publishers are not clearing out their buffers.
What is happening? I understood that using ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 would force all dds traffic to go via lo interface, and be super quick. But it seems that dds/ros2 traffic still depends a lot on what physical interfaces are available. If someone can explain this it would be good
